# Data transfer between two seperate application in angular 6 , What are the available options?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Consider two different applications

App1 runs on port http://localhost:**4200**/

App2 runs on port http://localhost:**4201**/

Please share what all are the available options to share a

1. **common json between these two applications**.
2. **component with some functionality .**

Sample [used just as visual sample to explain the scenario]

Consider if dashboard 2 & 3 run as two different app in two different port

http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.3/dashboard_2.html

http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.3/dashboard_3.html

Requirement is to

1. **Share the logged in user details json between this 2 apps** [tried achieving through local storage - not working]
2. As dashboard 2 & 3 app have the same sidepanel - **How to use one common sidepanel component with 
   functionalities**

Please help with some sample details to achieve this

Comment: What is your backend? SignalR , Websocket are good ways for comminication of applications

Comment: Not planning to sent any details to backend - Between angular application only.  Backend used is Spring boot.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as your apps are running on different ports, I would expect the browser to block attempts to communicate browser-internally for security reasons. It would be easier if you get help from the local servers (you need to have some running any, otherwise localhost:4200 and localhost:4201 would return 404).